# React, redux-form image preview

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm using React with Redux-Form and I'm trying to display the preview of an image in a file input. I managed to preview the image, however the image only previews if I change the focus out of the file input after selecting the file (instead of previewing it right after selecting the file).

This is the approach i took:

```
<div className="form-group">
    <label htmlFor="exampleInputFile" style={{ width: '100%' }}>
        <img id="team-logo-img" className="img-responsive center-block" src="http://placehold.it/180" />
        {this.renderImagePreview()}
    </label>
    <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" {...teamLogoField} value={null} onChange={this.readURL(this)} />
</div>
```

And my readURL function:

```
readURL(input) {

    input = input.props.fields.teamLogoField.value;

    if (input && input[0]) {
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function (e) {
            jQuery('#team-logo-img')
            .attr('src', e.target.result);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input[0]);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to preview the image right after the user selects a file ? or if there's a better approach to preview images using react redux-forms i'm listening!

========================================================================
Edit 1:

The approach I'm using is based on this :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL

which has worked for me when not using react

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found a solution: i updated my readURL function to this:

```
updatePreview(event, teamLogoField) {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (e) => {
        $('#team-logo-img').attr('src', e.target.result);
     };

    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    teamLogoField.onChange(event);
}
```

and called it on the onChange handle or the input as follows:

```
onChange={ (event) => {this.updatePreview(event , teamLogoField)} }
```

I believe this is and easy way to preview images in a form, however as I stated before: If someone has a better approach to this, I'm listening!

===========================================================================
**Edit 1**

Looks like you have to pass the redux-form field object into the onChange Handler to call redux-form own onChange so the new state of your field can be updated

===========================================================================
**Edit 2**

I found a more react-ish approach to do this, in my IMG element, y set the src to be a variable in my component state, and in my updatePreview function, in the onload block I updated the value of the variable, and you are done!